# use different calculate in slicer selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that have invoice data for different season that these are repeated value for different season,

I want to calculate sum invoice for distinct issuekey when slicer in All selection and calculate sum invoice for selection item,

for example when slicer is "spring2020" calculate Sum(invoice) where seasonindex= 1

and when All selected calculate  Sum(Max(invoice)) for distinct(issuekey)

My table:

| customer | issuekey | season | seasonindex | invoice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| H | A | spring2020 | 1 | 100 |
| Y | B | spring2020 | 1 | 120 |
| H | A | SUMMER2020 | 2 | 200 |

my expectation is like below:

All selection in slicer:  my chart show 200 for Customer "H" and show 120 for customer "Y"

Select spring2020: my chart show 100 for Customer "H" and show 120 for customer "Y"

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, there will only be one entry per customer per season, in which case this will do:

```
Measure = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(InvoiceTable[issuekey]),
    CALCULATE( MAX(InvoiceTable[invoice]) )
  )
```

Otherwise, if there can be multiple entries per customer per season, then you'll need:

```
Measure = 
  var isSeasonSliced = CALCULATE(ISFILTERED(InvoiceTable[season]), ALLSELECTED(InvoiceTable[season]))
  return IF(
    isSeasonSliced,
    SUM(InvoiceTable[invoice]), 
    SUMX(
      DISTINCT(InvoiceTable[issuekey]),
      CALCULATE( MAX(InvoiceTable[invoice]) )
    )
  )
```